# Mockitoを使ったTextViewのテストについて

Tags: android, junit, mock

Androidで次のようなプログラムを作成しテストしようとしています。

テスト対象のクラス

```
public class Sample {
    public void errorCheck(TextView textView) {
        if (textView.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            textView.setError("入力してください");
        }
    }
}
```

テストクラス

```
public class SampleTest {
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    private TextView mockTextView;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(mockTextView.getText()).thenReturn("");
        assertThat(mockTextView.getError().toString(), is("入力してください"));
    }
}
```

テストを実行すると（当然ですが）mockTextView.getError()がnullのため、NullPointerExceptionが発生します。

テストクラスでsetErrorされたことを確認したいため、次のようなモックは避けたいと考えています。

```
when(mockTextView.getError()).thenReturn("入力してください");
```

SampleクラスのsetErrorメソッドで「入力してください」と入力されたことをテストする方法はあるでしょうか？
今回は実機やエミュレーター上でのテストは重いので、できればそういったものを使わないようにテストしたいと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
public class SampleTest {
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    private TextView mockTextView;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(mockTextView.getText()).thenReturn("");
        ArgumentCaptor<String> stringCaptor = 
            ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        doNothing().when(mockTextView).setError(stringCaptor.capture());

        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.errorCheck(mockTextView);

        assertThat(stringCaptor.getValue(), is("入力してください"));
    }
}
```

ArgumentCaptorをセットして、呼び出し先でセットされた値をチェックすることができるようになりました。